# Rails link_to :method => :put send a GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest, put

I'm trying to use link_to to send PUT request but every time i send a GET request instead.

I tried :

```
<%= link_to raw('Valider'), roommates_join_path(:reference => var['reference']), :method => :put, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

in my browser I get :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-method="put" href="/roommates/join" rel="nofollow">Valider</a>
```

my routes.rb:

```
 put 'roommates/join'
```

When I click :

> No route matches [GET] "/roommates/join"

Comment: Could you please post your application.js file? Do you have javascript enabled in your brawser?

Comment: Check your gemfile and see if you have jquery-rails installed.

Comment: @hidewak did you solve it?

Comment: @hidewak try to disable AdBlock or anything else that could mess with js on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem where I use `link_to path, method: :put, data: {}` and it fire AJAX to `GET` and `PUT`.

Change the `link_to` to `button_to` to use the actual form instead of using `jquery_ujs` fixes the problem. Though, I did not really find put the is the cause.

Comment: ```button_to``` working well for ```put``` method, but I have to use link_to cause css with so on.

Answer (score 0):

This blow of code is `device gem`'s button_to, link_to code.
If you use rails7, It will be not working put, delete, so on except get method.

There is why not working put method with `link_to` https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/link-to-rails-7/79024

Add `data: {"turbo-method": :delete}` in `link_to`

button_to

```
<%= button_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %>
```

link_to

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, data: {"turbo-method": :delete} %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you include your application's javascript in your layout.

For example, if you are using the default 'application' layout, ensure you include the application javascript in your `<head/>` like so:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<head> 
  ... 
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  ...
</head>
```